# Tilt BufferedImage about the x-axis

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage, jai

**My project**: I'm creating a map/terrain from an `int[]` and the output is a `BufferedImage`.

**Problem**: I want to tilt the `BufferedImage` backwards (about the x-axis) 25 degrees.

That is to say, I want to convert this:

```
 _____
|     |
|     |
|     |
 -----
```

into something like this

```
   ____
  /    \
 /      \
/        \
----------
```

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7012847/1201423) and it sounds like the `PerspectiveTransform` from JAI might do the trick.

**Question**: How can the `PerspectiveTransform` be applied to the `BufferedImage`? Is this the right way of tilting the image back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the JHLabs filters:
http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html

and especially the "PerspectiveFilter".

EDIT:

```
public void perspective() throws Exception{
    BufferedImage srcImage = ImageIO.read(new File("flower.jpg"));
    BufferedImage destImage = null;

    int w = srcImage.getWidth();
    int h = srcImage.getHeight();

    PerspectiveFilter perspectiveFilter = new PerspectiveFilter();
    perspectiveFilter.setCorners(w/4, 0, w-w/4, 0, w, h, 0, h);     
    destImage = perspectiveFilter.filter(srcImage, destImage);

    ImageIO.write(destImage,"jpg",new File("modified_flower.jpg"));
}
```

This code will transform an image from this:
[image: original image]

to this:
[image: modified image]

Comment: This looks like it might have potential, will give it a shot. Will accept this answer for the time being, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Java3d, or do your own calculations. Basically, you have a 3d rotation of a plane with a texture.